# Title attributes on Permalinks for posts and products

Tags: permalinks, title, customization

I need to add title attributes to my wordpress links for new posts, pages and products on a website. This is for the actual post/page/product and not within content.

For example if I create a post/page/product i add a title 'Product One' this generates the permalink 'product-one' **Product One** which is great however i want to add a title attribute and can't seem to find a way of doing this so it will become **Product One**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to achieve

Comment: Title attribute is intended to show the additional information as a tooltip. Can be useful with such tags as `<abbr>` or `<input>`. Why do you want to duplicate the information already shown in the link text? If you dream about SEO effect, you should know there is no evidence it helps even remotely.

Comment: Did you find how to do this?